# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl, ssl-certificate

I'm trying a get request using the certs I downloaded from `https://host:port`.

[image]

```
url = 'https://host:port'

x = requests.get(url, verify = "file.crt")
prettified_json = json.dumps(x.json(), indent=4)
print(prettified_json)
```

I tried it both with crt and pem file. Same result.

Top certificate returns error.

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get issuer certificate
```

Bottom one return error

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain.
```

I tried checking the certificates using curl.

```
curl --cacert "file.crt" "https://host:port/"
```

It returns a valid json response.

I know I can set `verify = False`(I tried it and it works), but it's a temporary insecure measure. So I would prefer not to.

I tried adding certs to my cacert.pem like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76940159/python-delta-sharing-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-self-signed-cert), it didn't help.
I also tried creating a separate pem file in my working dir and appending both certs there. It didn't help.

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the full certificate chain, including the root CA certificate and any intermediate certificates. The chain should be in the correct order:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Domain certificate
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Intermediate CA certificate
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Root CA certificate
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Combine both of these certificates into one CA bundle file. You can simply do it using any text editor. Or use *cat* if you use Linux:

```
cat first_cert.pem second_cert.pem > combined_cert.pem
```

Comment: I tried appending the two certs in different order. It didn't work. I asked the admin for some more certs. One of them fixed my problem.